# GATT internal error after writing characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I've been attempting to read the glucose measurement records from a BLE device with the [Glucose service](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.glucose.xml). I'm able to successfully connect to the device and read new records when they are taken, but when I request a list of previous records I receive a callback with status 129 ("GATT_INTERNAL_ERROR"). No other callbacks occur afterwards, and eventually the transfer times out.

As I understand it, to retrieve the records I need to write a request to the [Record Access Control Point characteristic](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.record_access_control_point.xml). After receiving the request the device should respond by spitting out the requested records.

My request code looks like:

```
private void requestRecords() {
    byte[] requestValue = new byte[] {0x01, 0x01};
    racpCharacteristic.setValue(requestValue);
    bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(racpCharacteristic);
}
```

Where the {0x01, 0x01} enumeration corresponds to {"Request stored records", "All records"}.

The setValue() and writeCharacteristic() operations both return true, indicating success. My BluetoothGattCallback then receives an onCharacteristicWrite() callback for the RACP characteristic. However, the status returned by the callback is 129 (internal error) instead of the expected 0 (success).

I believe I also need to enable indications for the RACP characteristic (and/or notifications for the Measurement characteristic) to receive the records. But the enabling process appears to work correctly, and I receive the same error regardless of which combination of notifications/indications I use (if any). So I don't think the error is related, but for completeness here is the notification/indication code, which runs before the record request code:

```
private static final String DESCRIPTOR_UUID = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

...

private void enableNotifications(BluetoothGattCharacteristic char) {
    bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(char, true);

    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(DESCRIPTOR_UUID);
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = char.getDescriptor(uuid);

    boolean usesIndications = characteristicUsesIndications(char);
    descriptor.setValue(usesIndications ?
            BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE :
            BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

    bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
}
```

I make sure to wait for the corresponding onDescriptorWrite() callback before performing subsequent operations. E.g. enableNotifications(measurementChar) -> onDescriptorWrite() -> enableNotifications(racpChar) -> onDescriptorWrite() -> requestRecords()

Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong? I don't believe it's the device, as my iOS counterpart is able to retrieve the records successfully. I know some phones don't work well with BLE, so for the record I am testing with a Samsung Galaxy S5. As previously mentioned, it is able to receive new records from the BLE device, so hopefully the error isn't device-related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must enable notifications for the Glucose Measurement AND the Glucose Measurement Context before configuring the RACP for indications.  Some glucose meters allow only enabling the indications for the RACP but as a generalized practice, you should enable the (2) measurement notifications and the (1) RACP indication before writing to the Record Access Control Point.

Comment: it is conceivable that a glucose meter reports records without measurement context and without enabling notifications for those 'missing'  measurement context messages if the glucose record did not have this information to begin with.  Even glucose meters that don't send measurement context with every patient record should have the measurement context enabled for sending notifications.  Then when you send a record request using RACP, measurements & context will be enabled and it should all work :)

Comment: Thank you so very much, this was exactly what I was missing. You have saved me from the unending nightmare that is Android Bluetooth. Out of curiosity, could you point me to the documentation which indicates that this characteristic is necessary? I could have sworn I'd triple checked all the relevant documentation.

Comment: @stphven
For anybody else looking for this: You can go to https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/, then type Glucose in th search, then by reading **Record Access Control Point** and **Glucose Measurement** sections of `Glucose Profile` and `Glucose Service` pdfs you can learn about this topic.